# java.net.BindException

Tags: android

When I am sending real time audio from udp socket then there is an exception throw java.net.BindException : cannot assign requested address. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the port you are specifying is not used by some other process. And you are specifying that exception is occurring when you are sending packet, but I think it might be occurring at socket creation time.